How to change headers of an E-Mail inplace (via IMAP)
I have some E-Mails without a Date header in an Inbox. That's why they appear incorrectly in my MUA (Mozilla Thunderbird). So I would like to fix this.
There is an extension, with which I could manually edit the headers of a message. However, what it really does, is creating a new message and deleting the old one.
Is there a method to modify a message via IMAP or in another way generally?
How could I use that method, without manually talking to the server.

No.  IMAP messages are immutable, by definition.  If they were not, nothing would know whether they needed to resync them or not.
From RFC 3501, 2.3.1.1, statement 4:
         4) The combination of mailbox name, UIDVALIDITY, and UID
        must refer to a single immutable message on that server
        forever.  In particular, the internal date, [RFC-2822]
        size, envelope, body structure, and message texts
        (RFC822, RFC822.HEADER, RFC822.TEXT, and all BODY[...]
        fetch data items) must never change.  This does not
        include message numbers, nor does it include attributes
        that can be set by a STORE command (e.g., FLAGS).


Just curios, can that be bypassed, by manipulating the message on the server?

If you access to the filesystem or database, sure.  Like, on a unix server using mbox or Maildir you could theoretically just edit them in.  But any IMAP/POP clients cache would be out of date and the only way to fix it is to readd the account; or cause the server to change the UIDVALIDITY causing a full folder resync.

That is, to be clear, IMAP's promise is that any client that has downloaded a message (with a certain identifier) can cache it forever until either the message is changed (via getting a new UID), or the entire  folder is invalidated (by changing the UIDVALIDITY)

I see. So if I drop insisting on inplace, is there a neat way to do that?

I do not have a suggestion of a great way to do this (and tools are offtopic anyway).  Through the IMAP protocol, you can use FETCH to get it, edit it, then APPEND a new one and delete the old one.  It's probably gonna be tedious anyway.
With Thunderbird you could download the file as .eml, edit it, and probably drag and drop it to reupload it, but not sure about that last step.
